# I'am trying to hide and show data in card component from reactstrap

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I am trying to show and hide the data with the help of selecting other card, but when I am selecting one card all cards are showing rather than one card, that data is dynamic data.

I am trying to pass the id to show particular data in one card I can't able to achieve that.

```
{this.state.Installers.map((installer, index) => (
    <Card onClick={this.toggle.bind(this,installer)} >
        {installer.firstname_en} 
        <div>
            <div style={ hidden } class="col-md-12">
                <Card>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <label htmlFor="firstName" className="fname" style={{ fontFamily: "Roboto" }}>First Name : {data.firstname}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <label htmlFor="lastName" className="lname" style={{ fontFamily: "Roboto"}}>Last Name :{data.lastname}</label>
                    </div>
                </Card>
))}
```

Comment: Where is the method that is being invoked onClick?

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have provided, we couldn't decipher much, but you have to use combination of `Collapse` and `Card` to achieve what you want.

You need to store the currently selected elements ID in state and use the isOpen prop of Collapse to toggle the expansion.

```
import React from "react";
import { Collapse, Card } from "reactstrap";

class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      openCardID: null
    };
  }

  toggle = (installer) => {
    this.setState({
      openCardID: installer.id
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.state.Installers.map(installer => (
          <div role="presentation" onClick={() => this.toggle(installer)}>
            <Collapse isOpen={this.state.openCardID === installer.id}>
              <Card>
                <div className="col-md-12">
                  {installer.firstname_en}
                  <div className="col-md-7">
                    <label htmlFor="firstName" className="fname" style={{ fontFamily: "Roboto" }}>First Name : {data.firstname}</label>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-md-7">
                    <label htmlFor="lastName" className="lname" style={{ fontFamily: "Roboto" }}>Last Name :{data.lastname}</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Card>
            </Collapse>
          </div>
        ))}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default YourComponent;
```